# Xamarin ListView Images disappears on Scroll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Android.

I've this code for reading some files (stored inside an Android Phone)

```
public ImageSource Photo { get; set; }

public void LoadPhoto()
{
    var t = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("URI_OF_THE_PHOTO");
    var otherStream = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(t);
    Photo = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(() => otherStream);
}
```

then, in my XAML Page, inside a ListView's ViewCell i have this Image control:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Photo}"></Image>
```

Eveything works perfectly, the images (about 50) are loaded correctly and displayed inside the ListView.

**BUT when i scroll the ListView and the images go out of the screen, when i scroll them back, they're EMPTY ! Images are suddendly gone... DISAPPEARED !!!**

I've found a couple of StackOverflow's cases similar to this, but i can't get it to work with those solutions, they seem to not apply to my case.

Please, help, i'm stuck with this problem !

Comment: Try looking at the `CachingStrategy` for the `ListView`

Comment: unfortunately, I already tried setting it, with all its possible values ( RecycleElement / RetainElement / RecycleElementAndDataTemplate ) but it doesn't solve the problem at all :-(

Comment: you can try using FFImageLoading plugin. That can help you cache the images

Comment: Have you also tried setting the `CachingEnabled` property of the image to `true` ?

Comment: Yes, guys, i tried with CachingEnabled property of the image to true... it doesn't fix the problem. And i also tried with FFImageLoading plugin, but i can't get the plugin to work with these CONTENT PROVIDER'S STREAMS that i'm working with. I'm desperate !

Comment: You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738115/android-ffimageloading-using-uri-xamarin), so you get the images from uri? And  you want to use FFImageLoading to load the image from uri?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT your link solved the problem! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738115/android-ffimageloading-using-uri-xamarin). `FFImageLoading` will solve your problem.

Comment: @Alessandro, did it? I replaced `Image` with `CachedImage` and images disappear the same way as they did

Answer (score 1):

Use bindable stacklayout in xamarin forms 3.5..i had the same issue..solved..

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and after Google for a while, problem solved.(maybe this answer is too late)

```
public ImageSource ByteToImageSource(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    //this way, image in ListView will disapear on scroll
    //var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    //var retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

    // this way is fine
    var retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn));
    return retSource;
}
```

so I think in your case, you could do like this:

```
Photo = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(() => Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(t));
```